# What is the Gnome equivalent to KDE KControl?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

I'm looking for the gnome equivalent program to kControl.

I'm reading some online stuff and it says now run kControl, but I'm on gnome, so what is the program for gnome that serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`gnome-control-center`](https://launchpad.net/gnome-control-center). Its not exposed in the UI, but you can access it via the *Run As* dialog or the terminal.

[image: main screen of g-c-c]

Comment: It shows up for me in the System menu below Preferences and Administration.

Comment: hmmm. that's not the default IIRC, only if explicitly enabled.

Comment: I don't remember adding it, but I've done lots of things I don't remember later, so that's definitely a possibility :-)